# How to see javascript errors on chrome/safari mobile IOS 6

Tags: google-chrome, ios6, web

I'm wondering is there anyway to debug a problem on a Iphone 4s device running IOS 6.1. My website is not working and it appears that the javascript is broken. 
The problem only occurs on a mobile device and I would want to see the errors.

I tried emulation, take a look at [this tutorial](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/mobile-emulation)

but it works perfectly with it.

Answer (score 5):

[Here](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/Safari_Developer_Guide/GettingStarted/GettingStarted.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007874-CH2-SW8) is Apple's official answer to this question (look for "Safari on iOS" topic). It is possible to debug through your actual IOS device and it tells you how. Once you are connected you can debug the JavaScript and everything.

FYI, this uses Safari to debug. I have not seen a solution for using Chrome (though I really wish it were possible).

Comment: Too bad i must have MAC to be able to run that :(

Comment: You should be able to download Safari for Widows and enable the Developer Tools [HERE](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/Safari_Developer_Guide/2SafariDeveloperTools/SafariDeveloperTools.html) so that it will still work. Maybe?

Comment: if you mean this http://screencast.com/t/eKOIKdJ5W it works perfectly fine when running on the windows

Comment: Hmm. Must not work on Windows after all. After plugging in your phone you should see it listed in there along with the mobile Safari page you are on like this [screencast.com/t/EJ2inB6rIG3](http://www.screencast.com/t/EJ2inB6rIG3). This was a screenshot on my Mac. Sorry man.

Comment: That link to Apple is dead (404) -- any chance you have an updated link?

Comment: This answer should be accepted. You saved me a lot of time, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

For chrome (don't know from which version) you can use: 
`chrome://inspect` 
to log the  javascript errors.
For more information see 
https://blog.chromium.org/2019/03/debugging-websites-in-chrome-for-ios.html